# What is the correct database structure for this data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, normalization

I have two tables.

`Users` and `Education`

`Users` contains general user data.

`Education` contains records for each school attended.

`Education` would reference the user using a `userID` field.

Should I create a joining table? does this require normalization?

I have found issues when creating a foreign key linking the two tables... is this the reason for adding a linking table?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a Many-To-One relationship between Education and Users.  That is, a single User may have more than one Education.  In that case creating a Foreign Key (FK) from the Education table to the Users table sounds fine.

A joining table is only needed if there is a Many-To-Many relationship between tables.  For example, multiple Users can share the same Education.  Or you might want to store information about the relationship that should not be put on either entity.